# Mosfet Amplifier Problem

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, resistors, electrical

I'm currently working on a problem that wants me to obtain a gain of 500 using a mix of CG CS CD or cascode amplifiers or just a single topology. The Vout will be powering a resistive load of 50 ohms. I need a step in the right direction on what topology to use.

VDD  = 3v
VDSTAT = 0.25V
AV = 500

Update::::

So I have only been able to obtain a gain of 400 and cant get much more. Any ideas on where im going wrong. Here is my HSPICE Simulation. max length and width of the mosfets is 10um and min is 0.15um.

```
Vdd 2 0 DC 3
Vb 3 0 DC 1.75
Vin 5 0 DC 1.25

X1 1 5 0 0 nmos_ee435 width=4u length=10u
X2 1 3 2 2 pmos_ee435 width=8u length=10u


.SUBCKT nmos_ee435 d g s b width=4u length=10u
M1 d g s b nmos_internal W='width' L='length'
+ AD='width*2e-6' AS='width*2e-6' PD='4e-6+width' PS='4e-6+width'
.MODEL nmos_internal NMOS LEVEL=1 uo=400 vto=1 lambda='1e-6/length*0.1'
+ tox=6.903n gamma=1 phi=0.6 cgdo=0.5n cgso=0.5n cj=0.001 mj=0.5 pb=1
+ cjsw=0.1n mjsw=0.5 capop=0

.ENDS

.SUBCKT pmos_ee435 d g s b width=8u length=10u
M2 d g s b pmos_internal W='width' L='length'
+AD='width*2e-6' AS='width*2e-6' PD='4e-6+width' PS='4e-6+width'
.MODEL pmos_internal PMOS LEVEL=1 uo=200 vto=-1 lambda='1e-6/length*0.1'
+ tox=6.903n gamma=1 phi=0.6 cgdo=0.5n cgso=0.5n cj=0.001 mj=0.5 pb=1
+ cjsw=0.1n mjsw=0.5 capop=0

.ENDS

.OP

.tf V(1) Vin

.END
```

Comment: Can you do this in one stage? with a output buffer to handle 50 ohms? Sure. Use long channel CS, perhaps cascaded to avoid Cmiller, and use a Pch Current Load for high one-stage gain. Then you need to use DC_feedback to stabilize the operating point. That feedback might just be 1_Ohm/500_Ohm, or 100_Ohms/50,000_Ohms or similar.

Comment: Well in the design constraints it says I can do it any way I want as long as I can get a gain of 500 and have a load of 50 ohms. The less mosfets the better because we are also designing for space constraints.

Comment: In the transistor that acts as an active load set a very high value on L to increase your ro of the active load.You can also set a casocde active load to increase your ro and your gain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will advice you to use 2 stages.

First stage should be CS amplifier and the output will be the input for a CD amplifier which will operate like a buffer.

So, the first stage will give you very high gain(maybe if you design with active loads and properly values for W/L) and then the CD has the ability to give you the same gain(usually a little smaller) for every load you connect.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm going to work on this and see if I can get some results. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This did help solve my question. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: That's great! mjstanley